# How to split a string and only return remaining values?

Tags: javascript, string

I am working with a string that I would like to split and only return the remaining values.

The string looks as follows:

```
let str = "service.annual.returns"
```

I want to remove the "service" part of the string and only return "annual.returns".

I believe I can accomplish this with the .split() method, but not sure how the expression would look to get the desired result.

Apologies for being vague on the question. I indeed want to remove the first index, as the convention of the system I'm working on is to have a 'TYPE' appended to the name of a given element. For example, "Service" is just one such type, there are other instances such as "Tax": tax.annual.return, tax.zero.rated or another example is 'Media": media.youtube...this is important for the backend, but when showing the data to the frontend, I do not have to show the appended 'TYPE' formatting....that is only for the backend. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

No need to even convert to an array:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf(".")+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` method, and `indexOf` to get the `index` of the first dot and skip by plus by one.

```js
let str = "service.annual.returns"
const result = str.slice(str.indexOf('.') + 1)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first "word"

```
str.split(".").slice(1).join(".")
```

And if you can have many "service" or not in the start of the string

```
str.split(".").filter(function(e){return e != "service";}).join(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

A RegExp solution:

```
"service.annual.returns".match(/(?<=\.)([^.]+)/g)
// [ 'annual', 'returns' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways to achieve this **:**

- By using the [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method (Recommended)

```js
// Input string
let str = "service.annual.returns";

// Find the first index of '.' by using `.indexOf` method and then get the sub string from the input string based on the index. 
console.log(str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1));
```

- By splitting the `str` into an array based on the `.` and then remove the first element from an array and join back.

```js
let str = "service.annual.returns";

console.log(str.split('.').slice(1).join('.'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const newStr = str.split(".").filter(el => el != "service").join(".")
```

Comment: This is dependent on *only* the first word equalling "service".

Comment: @danh no it is not

Comment: with `str = "service.abc.service.def"`, newStr will be `abc.def` Am I mistaken? Also, it may be that the OP intends *any* first word to be removed, using service as just one example.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, if you want to remove the first index then yes. If you want to remove all "service"s then filter is fine. Both solutions can be inferred due to vagueness of the post.

Comment: Apologies for being vague on the question. I indeed want to remove the first index as the convention of the system I'm working on is to have a 'TYPE' appended to the name of a given element. For example Service is just one such type, there are other instances such as tax.annual.return, tax.zero.rated or another example is media.youtube...this is important for the backend, but when showing the data to the frontend, I do not have to show the appended 'TYPE' formatting....that is only for the backend. I hope this makes it a bit clearer